# jQuery find child based on class selector matching parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find the descendants of a particular node using the jquery `.find()` method. I have noticed that `.find()` doesnt match elements based on properties of parents above the current node in the tree. The first find returns 0 elements, but the second find returns the element I was searching for. My question is, is this a limitation of the selector pattern allowed for the find method and is find the only jquery function that has this limitation? I would have expected both of these to return the same element. Also, is there another jquery method that would more succinctly accomplish the same thing as second one. This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do and I cannot remove the `.find('.input-group')` as this is an input into my function.

```js
$(document).find('.input-group').find('.form-group .form-control')
$(document).find('.input-group').find('.form-control').filter('.form-group .form-control')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
       <input type="checkbox" aria-label="CVV Disabled" value="">
    </span>
      <input id="vtCvv" name="vtCvv" type="password" class="form-control" required="true" data-bv-field="vtCvv">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why dont you just use `$('.form-group .input-group .form-control')`

Comment: I realize i could do that in this simple example. Thats why I said that I cannot remove the `.find('.input-group')`. My function is accepting a jquery object and I dont have control over the input. I am just trying to find all descendants of the input that would match the '.form-group .form-control' selector if it were run from the document root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks for a descendant of an element. You're trying to find a parent and then a descendant.

You could find `.input-group`, then traverse backwards through the DOM to the "closest" `.form-group` using [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then you could navigate down to `.form-control` like so:

```
$(document).find('.input-group').closest('.form-group').find(".form-control")
```

or you could use [**.parent()**](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to backtrack to `.form-group` like so:

```
$(document).find('.input-group').parent().find(".form-control")
```

I prefer `.closest()` because if another element were to be added between `.input-group` and `form-group` the parent would be different, but `.closest` would still work.

Comment: This is what I suspected. I was hoping that since other jquery methods like `.filter()` and `.is()` will take parent nodes into consideration when processing a selector that the `.find()` or some other descendant searching function would also have that behavior. Unfortunately I will probably have to stick with my `.find().filter()` solution because I do not know whether the input to my function will be a jquery object that is above or below the `.form-group` element in the DOM so i cant use `.closest()`

Comment: @park896 To add to that answer, you could also use `$('.form-group:has(.input-group) .form-control')` which do the same. I don't know what's faster though...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.form-group .input-group').find('.form-control');
```